# Why did Mojang remove "Super Secret Settings"?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So I remember back in 1.8 there was this button called "Super Secret Settings", or something pretty similar to that.

Now in 1.9, there is no such button, and why is that so? It was a really fun button to mess around with.

Also there's was a Twitch broadcasting button as well, but now it seems like it's gone too?

Comment: Asking why a developer did something is beyond the scope of this site. We can't read minds, and likely nobody from Mojang would respond here even if they were around due to company policy.

Comment: @Tim S - that's a pretty narrow viewpoint. The rationale for both of these decisions is freely discoverable online, and the question is entirely answerable.

Comment: Questions involving "why devs did X" time and time again have been labelled off topic here, regardless of whether or not the answer is discoverable. Regardless, I didn't downvote, and I didn't answer, so take my comment with a grain of salt.

Comment: @ire And is irrelevant. We're about *games*. Not what developers have said about them.

Comment: Good riddance tbh, I was getting sick of questions about how to turn off Super Secret Settings :-P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shader functionality accessible through Super Secret Settings is currently undergoing a full rewrite, according to Minecraft developer Eric Broes, and so the button was temporarily removed. It's possible it may not return and that shaders may come back with some other method of accessibility.

Source: [Twitter](https://twitter.com/_grum/status/627141591942209536)

EDIT: The Twitch functionality was completely removed in 1.9, see [here](https://help.mojang.com/customer/portal/articles/1374789-twitch-integration-in-minecraft). Unlike the Super Secret Settings, it does not seem like it will make a comeback.